# JavaScript regex - replacing \btext with html tag

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

const obj = {text: "The\bNew stylish \biPhone"}

I would like to replace all words in the above object that starts with '\b' followed by a single word with bold html tag with the identified word in the tag

i.e. text: "The\bNew stylish \biPhone" should be text:  `"The <b>New</b> stylish <b>iPhone</b>"`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can capture `\\b(\S+)` and replace it with < b>$1< /b >.

Here `\\b` matches literal `\b` and `(\S+)` matches any word or text in general and gets captured in group1 which you can use to replace the matched text with bold tags.

```js
const s = 'The \\bNew stylish \\biPhone';
console.log(s.replace(/\\b(\S+)/g, '<b>$1</b>'))
```

Just in case you want to limit any character set matching the world, change `\S+` to something like `\w` or `[a-zA-Z]` and so on.